# Need column values to be dispersed among multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the two tables as below :

SQL> select * from customer;

```
CUSTOMERID CUSTOMERNAME
---------- --------------
     1         A
     2         B
```

SQL> select * from cars;

```
 CARID CUSTOMERID MODEL
---------- ---------- ----------
     1          1 toyota
     2          1 honda
     3          2 suzuki
```

I need to write an SQL query which would give an output like below :
( Can we use PIVOT or UNPIVOT for this ? I am not sure ! )

```
CUSTOMERID  CUSTOMERNAME    Model1     Model2
----------  -------------   -------   --------
     1         A            toyota     honda
     2         B            suzuki     NULL
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function & do conditional aggregation :

```
select customerid, customername,
       max(case when seq = 1 then model end) as model1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then model end) as model2
from (select c.*, cr.model, 
             row_number() over (partition by c.customerid order by cr.MODEL) as seq
      from customer c inner join
           cars cr
           on cr.customerid = c.customerid
     ) t
group by customerid, customername;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two values, you can use aggregation:

```
select cu.customerid, cu.customername,
       min(ca.model) as model1,
       nullif(max(ca.model), min(ca.model)) as model2
from customers cu join
     cars ca
     on ca.customerid = cu.customerid
group by cu.customerid, cu.customername;
```

If you have an indeterminate number, I would recommend aggregating them into a string or array.  That syntax depends on the database, but typical syntax is:

```
select cu.customerid, cu.customername,
       listagg(ca.model, ',') within group (order by ca.model) as models
from customers cu join
     cars ca
     on ca.customerid = cu.customerid
group by cu.customerid, cu.customername;
```